# Database Sync Online/Offline

Tags: java, database

I have created my java application for storing data in it. My laptop is not connected to Internet while I'm on work but it is connected when I'm home. 
Is there any way I can store data anywhere while offline and when It gets online it automatically syncs with the online server and I can see my data through my phone or tablet.

Comment: What kind of data are you storing inside your app ? custom datas (like a todo list) or files (like a dropbox app) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. Two, actually:

1. You can teach your application to store data in memory or files if it's not connected and synchronize manually when it gets back online.
2. You can create a local copy of your database and create a MASTER-MASTER replication between your server and local copy. This way all changes will be synchronized automatically once you get back online.

The particular implementation will really depend on your requirements and database type.